# How to convert t[i][j] to pointer style reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For example
`t[i]` is `*(t+i)`

How it will be for
`t[i][j]`?

In my opinion   `*(*(t+i)+j)` but not sure.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you have is correct. `t[i][j]` may be written as `(t[i])[j]`, so you may then apply the "1D" rule recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know how the data is stored in memory, as you want to operate on pointers. For 2-dimensional arrays there is no significant difference - the "rows" just tells how many "cells" the app should skip.

Let's assume for a while, that `t` is an integer, so when you have an array, which looks like this:

> |3|4|5|
>
> |6|5|4|

it will look, in fact like

> |3|4|5|6|5|4|

as stored in memory. The array means that the program has to "skip" after 3rd value in array `x[3][2]`, then `t[i][j]` would look like `*(*(t+i)+j)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. `t[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(t + i) + j)`.